# How to replace one parameter in Vuejs router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

We have a multi-level multi-tenant application, where the hostname identifies the 'supplier' account, but the customer account is actually part of the URL.

For instance, we have routes set up as follows:

```
/:locale/app/:customer_id/invoices
```

At the top of the page, we have a drop down with all customer ID's the user has access to.  The idea basically is that when a user changes the customer, the route changes from  `/nl/app/4/invoices` to `/nl/app/5/invoices`for instance.  So basically what I want to do is tell VueJs router to take the current route, and just change one parameter value in that route.

As you can imagine: the same goes for the `:locale` parameter where we basically have a language switch on top.

I know you can use `$router.push` in combination with a named route, and pass the current params in, replacing the params I want to update, but that would mean I'd have to name every route, and I'd need to know what the routes name is when I do an update.

Isn't there a way to just ask VueJS Router to "give me the current route", and update one parameter?

I've searched a lot on SO as well as through other resources, but so far did not get a good result...

Comment: See [the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort), namely the note in bold. Afaik you will either need to name your routes or manually combine a path. If it's a large application with numerous paths then you can easily make route naming automatic which makes the problem largely obsolete. You can get the current route name from `$route`.

Comment: Yeah well that's the info I have.  I just don't understand there is not a more elegant solution.  Just naming the routes (yes, there are a lot...) for the sake of "replacing" one route parameter seems to be a lot of overhead in my opinion...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not really need named routes or manual path creation for this functionality. Router's `push` and `replace` methods support partial patches. You can build a simple reusable function to achieve this:

```
// This function expects router instance and params object to change
function updatePathParams($router, newParams) {

  // Retrieve current params
  const currentParams = $router.currentRoute.params;

  // Create new params object
  const mergedParams = { ...currentParams, newParams };

  // When router is not supplied path or name,
  // it simply tries to update current route with new params or query
  // Almost everything is optional.
  $router.push({ params: mergedParams });
}
```

In your component, you can use it like:

```
onClickHandler() {
  updatePathParams(this.$router, { locale: 'en-us' });

  // Sometime later
  updatePathParams(this.$router, { customer_id: 123 });
}
```

> Also, here I merged the params object with existing values to illustrate the idea. In reality, you don't need to pass all the **params**. If you wish to change just one param say, `customer_id`, then simply do: `$router.push({ params: { customer_id: 1234 } })`. Vue-Router is smart enough to retain the same route and keep other params (`locale` here) unchanged.

Comment: This is exactly what I need!  It seems to be undocumented though?  I will go and try asap and confirm here.  Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why this does not work with query?  Is it only to work with params?

Comment: @DavidHeremans, I have not tried it but that seems logical. Merging query object is not very elegant and useful in many cases. It is always better to override it. Otherwise, the developer would have a hard time cleaning up existing query params.

Comment: FYI - it seems to work with query and params, but not with hash.  I asked this on their issue tracker here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2868 - not too happy with the response, but hey - you can't have everything :-)

Comment: @DavidHeremans This does not work with query params unfortunately. I tried it and it wouldn't overwrite the merged object because it won't be able to adequately search the object keys

Comment: Note that the router will throw an error if you try to navigate to the url that you're currently at.  If the only thing you're modifying between navigations are the params, then you will need to handle the scenario where the params have the same values between both navigations