# Changing a parameter in Vue 3 router

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vuejs3, router

I was trying to change a route parameter with Vue router.
My route is the following :

```js
/document/:id?/:lang?/edit
```

Id and lang (language) are the parameters.
I want to change the parameter lang using JavaScript without altering the rest of the route. I tried applying the following solution (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383717/how-to-replace-one-parameter-in-vuejs-router#:%7E:text=If%20you%20wish%20to%20change,params%20(%20locale%20here)%20unchanged.-)). The solution was made for Vue 2 and not 3. So I tried to make an updated version.
This is my code :

```js
let params = this.$route.params
params.lang = 'en'
this.$router.push({params:params})
```

When I execute my code, there is no change in the route parameters nor an error logged in the console. Does anyone know a solution to this problem in Vue 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad way to change your route parameter like this.

Instead, replace your route with the same `name`, same `id`, but different `lang`:

```
  this.$router.replace({
    name: this.$route.name,
    params: {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      lang: 'en' // or whatever you want
    }
  })
```

Don't forget to watch for the route changes if needed:

```
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // if anything needs to be done when the route changes
    }
  }
```